# Increment size of lines inside table

Tags: html, html-table

```html
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped" border="5">
                <tbody>
                    <tr border="5">
                        <td border="5">Local IP Address</td>
                        <td border="5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"   aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr border="5">
                        <td border="5">Local Netmask</td>
                        <td border="5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"   aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Default Gateway</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"    aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Hello im trying to increment the size of the inside lines of the table but im only getting the outside lines incrementing...

im using

```
            <table class="table table-hover table-striped" border="5">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Local IP Address</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"   [(ngModel)] ="LocalIpAddress[1]" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Local Netmask</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"   [(ngModel)] ="LocalNetmask[1]"  aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Default Gateway</td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"   [(ngModel)] ="DefaultGateway[1]"  aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

and i am getting this:

[image: table]

what do i have to do to get also an increment in the size of the inside lines..?

Comment: Where is the CSS ?

Comment: @NawedKhan css file is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <style>
    .table-striped td {
        border: 2px solid #000;
    }
    </style>
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped" border="5">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Local IP Address</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)] ="LocalIpAddress[1]" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Local Netmask</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"   [(ngModel)] ="LocalNetmask[1]"  aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Default Gateway</td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control"   [(ngModel)] ="DefaultGateway[1]"  aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

use style="border:5" in the tr or td tags. tr are rows and td are columns I believe

Comment: Sorry it's been a while I used html. Try this ->  style="border:5" <- inside the tr and td tags with the arrows